# PHP mkdir not working -- may be related to Mac localhost

Tags: php, macos, apache, mkdir

I'm trying to execute the following code in my PHP script:

```
if (!is_dir($path . 'channel-partners/html/intro-letter/' . $name_url)) {
      mkdir($path . 'channel-partners/html/intro-letter/' . $name_url, 0777, true);
}
```

`$name_url` is a string passed in at runtime.  I get permission when I try to do this in my Mac localhost.  I'm wondering if the issue is not my script but the way Apache is set up on my Mac.  Do I need to do something special to configure Apache to allow it to create files and make directories (the file creation is not shown here)?

Comment: It's Apache usergroup which needs permission to create file and folders.

Comment: does `mkdir` function return `false`?

Comment: @Damien--how do I set the usergroup to have permissions?

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 -- I'm not sure if it's returning false or not. The error I get is permission denied.

Comment: if you are unable to create recursive folder(s) using 0777 mode in your php script.
Then try it by changing your current user to apache and test it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably set the appropriate rights for the apache user to your destination folder.

Comment: The folder that needs the permission is `channel-partners/html`.  How do I do that?

Comment: In the terminal with the chmod command or with the information view of the folder on osX (read and write for everyone)

Comment: If you set to the appropriate group, yes.

Comment: I get `you are not a member of group _www`

Comment: i don't know your configuration. you should juste add write right for others with chmod to your channel-partners folder with  
chmod -R o+w /pathTo/channel-partners

Answer (score 4):

The user or group that Apache is running as will need to have write permissions to the parent DIR. The default installation of Apache on Mac runs under a user & group named `_www`, so

`chgrp -R _www /the/parent/directory/here` should do the job. see `man chmod` `man chown` `man chgrp` for more info.

Comment: Sorry, yes. That command will make _www the group for  /the/parent/directory bare in mind, with this the group will need to have write access to the folder too. It may be worth you looking up the Unix permission structure.

Comment: I get `you are not a member of group _www`

Comment: `sudo chgrp -R _www /the/parent/directory/here`  then ensure they have read/write perms with `sudo chmod -R g+rw /the/parent/directory`

Comment: It took the command this time, but I still get the same error.